# how to set values of a CvPoint

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using a `CvPoint` structure in OpenCV and I need to assign a value to `x` and `y` fields of the structure.

Here is my code:

```
CvPoint* P1;
P2[0].x=32;
```

But the programs always block while trying to set the value.

Any idea about how to set these values?

Comment: You have created pointer variable of name `P1` & you are trying to assign values to pointer variable `P2`? You need to do something like `cvPoint P1 = cvPoint(32, 32);`

Comment: Since the question is tagged C++, you would be better off using a `cv::Point` object, anyway. Othwerwise retagging the question to C might be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first of all P1 is a pointer to an object of type P1. In order to assign something to an object's member via its pointer you need to use the **->** operator. If this pointer points to the beginning of an array you use the **operator[]** to access individual elements. This operator returns a reference for the given index, in this case **CvPoint&** .

**1. dynamic allocation of a single object**

```
CvPoint* P1 = new CvPoint(); // default construction of an object of type CvPoint
P1->x = 32;

// do something with P1

// clean up 
delete P1;
```

**2. dynamic allocation or an array**

```
CvPoint* points = new CvPoint[2]; // array of two CvPoints
points[0].x = 32; // operator[] returns a reference to the CvPoint at the given index
points[1].x = 32;

// do something with points

// clean up
delete[] points;
```

Since in both examples the new operator has been used, it is mandatory to pair them with a matching call to **delete** or **delete[]** in case of an array.

Answer (score 3):

no dynamic method:

```
CvPoint P1;

P1.x=32;

P1.y=32;

//////////////

CvPoint P2[2];

P2[0].x=32;

P2[0].y=32;
```